# Schoolboys sell insurance against canings

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to identify a featurette that accompanied *Raiders of the Lost Ark* at the movies, so  I guess I'd have seen it in 1981.

From memory, the featurette was set in a British public boarding school. A group of entrepreneurial students clean up by selling their classmates insurance policies that pay out if they get a beating. The headmaster gets wind of the scheme and tries to thwart the cocky little upstarts by giving the cane to every boy who bought insurance. Unable to pay on all the policies at once, and facing the wrath of their insurees, the gang solves the problem in some way I can't recall.  However, it involved the discovery of an arcane law or legal precedent allowing them to throw themselves a lavish party and *literally* consume their expenses.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sounds like UK short film [The Dollar Bottom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080643/combined) which was indeed from 1981.

> Light-hearted tale about an enterprising Edinburgh boarding school boy who sets up an insurance scheme for fellow pupils in 1953 against getting caned, which quickly earns him a small fortune.

Can't really find any good pics or clips, I'm afraid, just this one of the short winning an Oscar:

Comment: OMG how brilliant is the internet! Really didn't think that had a chance and it took less than 5 minutes. Thanks Walt! You're brilliant too.